# How can I recover missing Android files on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, android

My aunt lost her memos from her S5's built-in memo app yesterday, and, naturally, turned to her nephew for help :D

My first move was to plug the phone in to my (Windows 8.1) laptop, and try to use [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva), but I couldn't get to the phone's files through the Recuva wizard, even though I could find them in Explorer.

**What can I do to recover my aunt's memos?**

I have

- a Windows computer (8.1)
- the phone which (in case you forgot!) is a Samsung Galaxy S5 (Android 4.4.4)
- some missing files from the Memo app (which can hopefully be recovered! :)